# Version 2.6.12 of mongodb-org not found. Did you specify both version and release?

Tags: mongodb

I have a chef file like below:

```
"recipe[mongodb::mongodb_org_repo]",
"recipe[mongodb]",
```

and

```
"mongodb": {
    "config": {
      "dbpath": "\/data\/mongo\/mongodb\/",
      "logpath": "\/data\/ephemeral\/logs\/mongodb\/mongod.log",
      "smallfiles": true
    },
    "package_version": "2.6.12"
  },
```

After I run knife solo cook xxx.json
I got an error like this:

> Recipe: mongodb::install   * file[/etc/sysconfig/mongodb] action
>
> create_if_missing (up to date)   * template[/etc/mongodb.conf] action
>
> create_if_missing (up to date)   * template[/etc/init.d/mongod] action
>
> create_if_missing (up to date)   * yum_package[mongodb-org] action
>   install

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[mongodb-org]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
Version 2.6.12 of mongodb-org not found. Did you specify both version and release? (version-release, e.g. 1.84-10.fc6)

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mongodb/recipes/install.rb

 65: package node[:mongodb][:package_name] do
 66:   options packager_opts
 67:   action :install
 68:   version node[:mongodb][:package_version]
 69: end
 70:
```

...

I though the problem come from package_version.
Anyone can help me? Thanks.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByixKiOmifPMdEhkN2RQM2FCcXM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for myself.

> "mongodb": {
>       "config": {
>         "dbpath": "/data/mongo/mongodb/",
>         "logpath": "/data/ephemeral/logs/mongodb/mongod.log",
>         "smallfiles": true
>       },
>       "package_version": "2.6.12-1"   },

Thanks god, it works by chance. I don't know why it works. Anyone can explain is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful and led me to finding my answer by running the following at the ec2-user command line: `yum info mongodb-org.x86_64` 
which printed:

```
Available Packages  
Name        : mongodb-org  
Arch        : x86_64  
Version     : 3.6.3  
Release     : 1.amzn1  
Size        : 5.8 k
```

I concatenated the Version and Release to "3.6.3-1.amzn1".